# How to add Azure Internal load balancer (ILB) for an existing VMs

Tags: load-balancing, azure

Hoping someone can point me to the right direction. I'm not having much luck with the setup.

Here is the scenario and relevant (well, what I think is relevant but please ask if you need more) setup details.

- Resource Manager based deployment i.e. ARM based. I have no v1 or old ASM based resources in this setup.
- Everything in created in one Resource Group.
- 1 Regional vNet (e.g. myvNet1 in East US)
- It has three Subnets ( e.g. Backend (192.168.1.0/24), MidTier (192.168.2.0/24) and FrontEnd (192.168.3.0/24)
- The MidTier subnet is running two VM (e.g. VM1 and VM2)

The desire is to add an ILB in MidTier infront of them to load balance HTTPS traffic to these existing VMs (VM1 and VM2)

these two VM's already have a network interface so how can I assign/update/ replace the "existing" network interface with the one that were created as part of ILB creation steps?

When I try to assign backend network interface that I created for ILB, it complains that;

*Virtual machines with multiple network interfaces and virtual machines with a single network interface are not supported in the same tenant, also a virtual machine having a single network interface cannot be updated to have multiple network interfaces and vice-versa.*

When I try to delete the "already" assigned network interface from the VM's (VM1 and VM2) so that I can assign the ILB ones, it doesn't give me an explanation that whether it's allowed or not other then try it later...

*Failed to delete network interface 'vm011644'. Error: There was an error processing your request. Try again in a few moments.*

All the research I have done starts with the notion that a new subnet is being created and some even start by VM's are also being created as a part of this exercise but nothing on putting/dropping ILB in front of existing setup (perhaps I'm not looking closely)

Appreciate some guidance on this;

Thanks,

Note; the main link that I'm following is;

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-ps/

then I'm just using Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface and update-azurermVM to assign the network interface.

Answer (score 0):

if I remember correctly, you cant do it in the new portal (or maybe the old one too), you have to create new VM and assign the load balance. Or maybe you can create new VM using your existing VHD (only available in old portal)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating new set of VM's and attaching the network interfaces to get the ILB going. I'll circle back and update, if I hear anything new via my MS channel.